# Web service documentation (schemas, locations) discovery in SOA

Tags: wsdl, wso2, biztalk, soa

I need to make a recommendation on approaches for allowing web service (WCF) documentation (wsdl, schemas, locations etc.) to be stored and found. Being able to monitor the services would be a definite bonus.

This needs to be considered in the wider context of moving to an SOA built, where possible, with Microsoft technologies that should be accessible by clients from other frameworks. The aim is to develop a system in which clients do not need to change if a service is moved or new versions are brought online - it should be possible to write the client 'knowing' just one address / location which is capable of directing them appropriately.

Having a central location for the service documentation is important too; our Business Analysts should be able to find all they need to about the services we provide from a central place. We would also want (potentially) to expose that repository of service information to partners as well. I know we could generate wsdls and manually manage them (create a folder somewhere and zip them up before sending them out) but that seems very labour intensive and prone to error (on my part).

As I see it at the moment there are two broad approaches;

1. Write something bespoke that uses WS-Discoverability and [a dynamic routing service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146835/How-to-create-scalable-services-with-WCF-4-0-Route) which can respond to the client requests.
2. Get an off the shelf solution.

I have to say that an off the shelf solution is the most likely approach that will be accepted but I have to at least consider the alternatives. For the off the shelf solutions I have identified

1. BizTalk
2. [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) and [WSO2 Governance Registry](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/)

as possibly providing the features.

**What I need to know**
Am I right with my understanding of the broad approaches?
Are there any other approaches I should consider evaluating?

Specifically I also need to know pros and cons of any approach I consider and have an idea of how it could be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with I would definitely not go with Biztalk or any WS-Whatever SOAP based protocol.

Go simpler and you'll be an happy man in the end.

For the middleware I would go [Mass Transit](https://code.google.com/p/masstransit/)

or if you prefer, NServiceBus, which I'm not a big fan off, but which provides another level of enterprise support. If you choose to go with Event SOA you'd get async operations as a bonus.

With the middleware layer defined  it is time to define the API Layer. I would not expose my services to the outside world, and if the middleware is event based, the services within it they can only respond to events placed in the bus, so I would use ASP.NET Web API with a REST interface to get the requests to the outside, and based on the request type create the related message (command) and place it on the bus.

Way to high level but I hope it helps.